# Printing time behind your .css files, why?

Tags: css, time

In some sourcecodes i see this:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css?201007071609" type="text/css" />`

Now is my question: why do people print `201007071609` behind `style.css`?

Comment: Just to add to the answers: the number is a timestamp; probably the last modified date of the file. It's generated automatically by server-side code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This forces the browser to not load the css from cache  and rather take the latest version from the server

see [related article](http://www.stefanhayden.com/blog/2006/04/03/css-caching-hack/)

Another trick developers do is to add a random string or a timestamp to force refresh the css page.

Comment: Thanks all, 3 comments with the same answer should be right ;)

Answer (score 3):

That's a way to make sure that clients don't cache older versions of the same file.  If the URL is different, the client will retrieve the file from the server instead of from cache.  So, for example, if a new version of the site was published, that would be a way to make sure visitors see the right CSS.

Comment: Thanks all, 3 comments with the same answer should be right ;)

Answer (score 3):

This forces the browser to retrieve a fresh copy of the file, rather than loading a cached version.  This is important when your html has changed and requires an up to date css file to prevent it from displaying incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks all, 3 comments with the same answer should be right ;)